# Assignment problem with divisible tasks and hours

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

A general assignment problem is assigning a set of tasks(Ti) to a set of workers (Wi). Any agent can be assigned to perform any task, incurring some cost that may vary depending on the agent-task assignment. It is required to perform all tasks by assigning exactly one agent to each task and exactly one task to each agent in such a way that the total cost of the assignment is minimized.

[Assignment problem table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I7Fz.png)

For instance, Worker A can do Job1 in 9 hours, Job2 in 2 hours, Job3 in 7 hours and so on.

In my case, say Worker A has a total of 8 hours, can do 1/2 of Job1 in 3 hours, 1/4 of Job1 in 1/8 hours and so on, Worker B can do 1/3 of Job1 in 2 hours, 1/4 of Job2 in 5 hours similarly for other workers and job combinations. We need to assign fractional tasks to each of the workers so as to minimize the cost and maximize the task assignment.

Comment: What to solve for? What is asked?

Comment: Minimize the cost (number of hours), while maximizing the matching of persons with tasks

Comment: still appears unclear...

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the problem description